# Move Elements In An ArrayList Down One That Are Higher Than Specific Index

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a server that creates a new Thread when a client joins and puts it in an ArrayList (that is of the type EchoThread). It works great - creates a new JLabel for each one and updates their positions in my game near instantly, however if one leaves (that isn't the last client in the arraylist) then I want the server to move all of the clients (that are higher than the index of the client that left) down by one. I have tried many things, some partially working. Here is the method if somebody leaves, where i is equal to the index of the client that left:

```
public static void removeClient(int i) throws Exception {

}
```

I tried a couple of things, such as using a for loop to move each of the EchoThread's in the arrayList down by one, however they dont seem to work:

The ArrayList:

```
    static ArrayList<EchoThread> clients = new ArrayList<EchoThread>();
```

The for loop that I tried:

```
    for(int ii = i+1; ii < clients.size()-1; ii++){
        EchoThread e = clients.get(ii);
        clients.set(ii-1, e);
    }
```

I also tried to make a temporary arraylist that gets all of the elements in the clients arraylist added, except the index i, and then set the clients arraylist to equal the temporary arraylist, but it still failed.

Somebody said I could use a linked list, but I don't know how?

Edit:

```
p = a JPanel
f = a JFrame
clients = an arrayList<EchoThread>
clientinfo = a JLabel in EchoThread class
clientname = an arraylist of strings
clientpos = an arraylist of the positions of each client
info = a JLabel to show number of clients that are connected
```

Method:

```
public static void removeClient(int i) throws Exception {
    p.remove(clients.get(i).clientinfo);
    p.revalidate();
    f.validate();
    f.repaint();
    clients.get(i).clientinfo.setVisible(false);
    clients.remove(i);
    clientnames.remove(i);
    clientpos.remove(i);
    info.setText("Clients Connected: " + clients.size());

    for(int ii = i+1; ii < clients.size()-1; ii++){
        EchoThread e = clients.get(ii);
        clients.set(ii-1, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `remove` on the `ArrayList`?  That will shift everything past it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure you are calling removeClient in a thread-safe way. I'm guessing but it sounds like perhaps you're calling it from each EchoThread, which is not safe without synchronization, because (a) [the threads can trample all over each other's modifications to the list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html); and (b) [there is no guarantee threads will even *see* each other's modifications to the list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

Usually you could just add the [`synchronized` modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) on any methods that modify the ArrayList, which provides both mutual exclusion (preventing multiple threads from modifying it at once and corrupting it) and a *happens-before* relationship between calls to those methods (making sure threads see each other's changes to the list). However, that won't be enough here, because you are also using the method to modify Swing components. With few exceptions, Swing components must be accessed only from the single [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), so if you want to update the frame and you are on a different thread, you must first switch to the event dispatch thread.

In Java 8+, modify the beginning of your removeClient method as follows:

```
public static void removeClient(int i) {
    if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> removeClient(i));
        return;
    }

    // ...
```

In old versions of Java:

```
public static void removeClient(final int i) {
    if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                removeClient(i);
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    // ...
```

Once you are on the correct thread, removing the item from the list and moving the other items down the list really is as simple as calling `clients.remove(i);`, as the other answerers have said. You don't need that extra for-loop and it won't work.

Perhaps your problem is that although the list does move the items down, you have given those items their own index field, so after removing the item, its own index field no longer matches its actual position in the list? You could iterate the items in the list and reset the index field of each item to match its real position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
    clients.get(i).index = i;
```

(assuming you have some field `index` on your EchoThread objects).

However, that might not be the best approach. You don't necessarily *need* to keep track of the index, since you can perfectly well [remove the object itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) without knowing the index:

```
EchoThread client = ...;
clients.remove(client);
```

How to update your other lists, `clientnames`, `clientpos`? Well, you could find out the index by calling [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) on the first list. But that is ugly. You shouldn't really have all these separate lists. You should preferably have a class that encapsulates the various different fields for a single client including the "name" and "pos" fields, and make a list of those objects. You already have the EchoClient objects, so maybe you can just move the fields to that.

Comment: Nice answer, this may take a while to implement into my program. And you guessed very well :)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `clients.remove(i);`

Here's the implementation of `ArrayList#remove`.  As you can see, it uses System.arraycopy to slide the tail of the list down so you have an uninterrupted list.

```
/**
 * Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
 * Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their
 * indices).
 *
 * @param index the index of the element to be removed
 * @return the element that was removed from the list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to just go clients.remove(i), but it doesn't move the others down. The for loop works if there are two people and the first one leaves, but not if there are > 2.

Comment: You are mistaken.  It most certainly does move the tail of the list down.

Comment: I swear - it doesn't. They remain in the same index of they ArrayList and I get null pointer exceptions at the index of the one that left.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The API already does this for you with the `remove` method.

Taken from the docs:

> public E remove(int index)
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

Comment: I have tried to just go clients.remove(i), but it doesn't move the others down. The for loop works if there are two people and the first one leaves, but not if there are > 2.